# Как нарисовать кривые Безье (smooth lines) с библиотекой d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Вот в чем вопрос. Нужно нарисовать кривые Безье, а как не понятно.

Comment: у Безье обычно кривые, что ты имеешь ввиду под "прямые Безье"?

Comment: Уже исправил - кривые Безье а не прямые, вот как мой нос примерно.)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quadratic Bezier (3 точки):

```
d3.select('svg').append('path').attr('d', 'M 100,100 Q 200,100 200,200')
```

Cubic Bezier (4 точки):

```
d3.select('svg').append('path').attr('d', 'M 100,100 C 200,100 200,200 300,200')
```

Comment: Помогите доработать мой ответ. Нужно убрать заливку. Не знаю как это сделать.Заранее Всех благодарю.

Comment: @Michael Rovinsky Заходите пожалуйста почаще в гости

Answer (score 2):

Убрать заливку:

```
d3.select('path').attr('fill', 'none');
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Project 1.0.0.1</title>
<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
let x1=102
let y1 =100
//Quadratic Bezier (3 точки):
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("height", 1024)
   .attr("width", 1366);
//Cubic Bezier (4 точки):
let curve1 = canvas.append("svg").append('path').attr('d', `M ${x1}, ${y1} C 200,100 200,200 300,100`).attr('fill', 'none').attr("stroke", "blue")
let curve2 = canvas.append("svg").append('path').attr('d', `M ${x1}, ${y1} Q 200,100 200,200`).attr('fill', 'none').attr("stroke", "red")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: еще не понимаю это :  есть
`let x1=100 
let x2=120
`как эти переменные встроить в кривую Безье: вот так не работает:
`.attr('d', 'M x1,y1 C 200,100 200,200 300,100') `

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AO9HNlm.png

Comment: ` M ${x1} ${y1} C 200,100 200,200 300,100 `

Comment: вот такая кавычка ``` это шаблон строки https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Понимаю понимаю, я благодарен. у меня еще один вопрос с конкурсом. Он в топе. ответьте на него тоже. Вы Stranger выручаете на Ура. Я сейчас в Ереване, Аджяпняк, (Черемушки), ул. Маркаряна, дом 39. кв. 33. Заходите ко мне в любое время года с ночлегом. При себе ничего не нужно иметь. Буду рад Вас Встретить. Это не далеко от Республиканской больницы. Я серьезно. Но я нормальный, программист, биоинформатик. Просто разговариваю с птицами. ))

Comment: +37499018083 Вот мой мобильник. Nokia Dual Sim X2 Android 4.0

Comment: Вот моя Wi-Fi Net:      Nimbus 2020